# send.keys(tab) is restiiing the value in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Here is my code snippet -

```
span = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'effortAssign11')]")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '8';", span);
span.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
```

The send_keys(Keys.TAB) is clearing the value that is entered by execute script

Does any one having any idea a`enter code here`bout that ? I am new to selenium

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to send text to a text field? Are you trying to simulate pressing the TAB key?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ and the _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_

Answer (score 0):

Use **Action** chain for simulating keyboard action/event :

```
actions = ActionChains(browser)  
actions = actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)  
actions.perform()
```

Use this code after sending the value by execute script.